# How to replace properties using mapped types in Typescript

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

I have a Factory function that receives an object and if that object has  properties with a certain name, the factory converts those properties into methods.

How can I use mapped Types to correctly represent the type of the output object?

For example, let's say the convertible properties are foo, bar, baz:

```
interface IFactoryConfig {
   foo?: string;
   bar?: string;
   baz?: string;
}
```

And the replacement properties are:

```
interface IFactoryResult {
   foo(someParam: string): boolean;
   bar(): number;
   baz(otherParam: number): void;
}
```

If the input's type is

```
interface IInputObject {
   baz: string;
   notPredefined: string;
   aNumber: number;
   foo: string;
   aMethod(): void;
}
```

The factory replaces baz and foo with methods and returns:

```
interface IInputObject {
   baz(otherParam: number): void;
   notPredefined: string;
   aNumber: number;
   foo(someParam: string): boolean;
   aMethod(): void;
}
```

I'm trying to use mapped types to replace the properties:

```
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;

interface IFactory {
   <InputType extends IFactoryConfig, ResultType>(config: InputType): Omit<InputType, keyof IFactoryConfig> & Pick<IFactoryResult, ?>;
}
```

I don't know what to put in the Pick<> to pick from IFactoryResult the properties that also appear on InputType.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're just talking about the type-level stuff here, not run-time behavior.  You can use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) inside your mapped type to perform the check. Here's a general property replacer:

```
type ReplaceProps<T, From, To> = { [K in keyof T]:
  K extends keyof From ? T[K] extends From[K] ? K extends keyof To ? To[K] 
  : T[K] : T[K] : T[K]
}
```

The idea is that any property in `T` whose key and value type is also found in `From` and whose key is found in `To` will be replaced by the property type in `To`; otherwise it leaves the property alone.

Then you can use it like this:

```
type IInputObjectOut = ReplaceProps<IInputObject, IFactoryConfig, IFactoryResult>;
```

and inspecting `IInputObjectOut` you can see it matches your desired type:

```
type IInputObjectOut = {
  baz: (otherParam: number) => void;
  notPredefined: string;
  aNumber: number;
  foo: (someParam: string) => boolean;
  aMethod: () => void;
}
```

I *think* you could define your `IFactory` type like this, assuming it's supposed to be callable and behaves like `ReplaceProps` for its input type:

```
interface IFactory {
  <T>(config: T): ReplaceProps<T, IFactoryConfig, IFactoryResult>;
}

declare const iFact: IFactory;
declare const input: IInputObject;
input.foo; // string
input.aNumber; // number
const output = iFact(input); // ReplaceProps<IInputObject, IFactoryConfig, IFactoryResult>;
output.foo("hey"); // boolean
output.aNumber; // number
```

Does that work for you?  Hope it helps.  Good luck!